# Cell colours not getting overridden with excelJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, excel, exceljs

The function is taking a xlsx file as input initially it will validate the file and mark all error cells red and download it. User will remove the errors on red cells and reupload the file

In the excel sheet
The first row in the file is headers.
then for each column next two rows are merged and there is a instruction for each column data.

From row 4 there is actual data and we need to validate it
Suppose in the sheet if cell A5 has some error in its data, A5 will be marked as red and a new file is downloaded on user computer.

While reuploading, To validate it I need to first convert all the existing red columns in the input excel sheet to no coloured columns so that I can highlight new error columns in red.

```
import * as excelJs from "exceljs";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx-color";

import { validateIds } from "../../../../../services/admin/staff";
function getCellRef(row, col) {
  return XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ r: row, c: col });
}
function s2ab(s) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  const view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
  return buf;
}
function getRowCellRefs(worksheet, row, errorCols) {
  const range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet["!ref"]);
  const cellRefs = [];
  for (let col = range.s.c; col <= range.e.c; col++) {
    if (errorCols.includes(col)) {
      cellRefs.push(getCellRef(row, col));
    }
  }
  return cellRefs;
}
function isValidDate(date) {
  if (!(date instanceof Date)) {
    return false;
  }
  if (isNaN(date.getTime())) {
    return false;
  }
  if (date.getFullYear() < 1000 || date.getFullYear() > 9999) {
    return false;
  }
  if (date.getMonth() < 0 || date.getMonth() > 11) {
    return false;
  }
  if (date.getDate() < 1 || date.getDate() > 31) {
    return false;
  }
  if (date.getHours() < 0 || date.getHours() > 23) {
    return false;
  }
  if (date.getMinutes() < 0 || date.getMinutes() > 59) {
    return false;
  }
  if (date.getSeconds() < 0 || date.getSeconds() > 59) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
function elementCount(arr, element) {
  return arr.filter((currentElement) => currentElement == element).length;
}
function isUnique(arr, item) {
  if (elementCount(arr, item) > 1) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
function isValidPhone(phone) {
  if (typeof phone !== "number") {
    return false;
  }
  const regex = /^\d{10}$/;
  return regex.test(phone);
}

export const validateData = async (
  e,
  setAddData,
  collegeShortForm,
  teacherIdFormat
) => {
  let errorCells = [];
  let blob;
  let p = [];
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = async function (e) {
    const data = e.target.result;
    let emailArray = [];
    let phoneNumberArray = [];
    let staffIds = [];
    let userIdArray = [];

    const workbook = new excelJs.Workbook();
    await workbook.xlsx.load(data);

    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);

    p = worksheet.getSheetValues().slice(1);
    const headers = p.shift();

    p.shift();
    p.shift();
    console.log(headers);
    if (!headers.includes("User ID")) {
      worksheet.getCell("R1").value = "User ID";
      worksheet.getCell("R2").value =
        "Please change the userIds which are in red cells";
      worksheet.mergeCells(`R2:R3`);
      const columnR = worksheet.getColumn("R");
      columnR.width = 25;
    }
    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < p.length; rowIndex++) {
      const staffId = p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("Staff Id")];
      const email = p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("Email")];
      const phoneNumber = p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("Phone Number")];
      const fname = p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("First Name")];
      const lname = p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("Last Name")];
      staffIds.push(staffId);
      emailArray.push(email);
      phoneNumberArray.push(phoneNumber);
      console.log(fname, `R${rowIndex + 4}`);
      if (!p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("User ID")] && fname && lname) {
        userIdArray.push({
          userId: generateUserId(
            fname,
            lname,
            collegeShortForm,
            teacherIdFormat
          ),
        });
      } else if (
        p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("User ID")] !== undefined &&
        p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("User ID")] !== ""
      ) {
        if (
          p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("User ID")] !== undefined ||
          p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("User ID")]
        ) {
          userIdArray.push({ userId: p[rowIndex][headers.indexOf("User ID")] });
        } else {
          errorCells.push(`R${rowIndex + 4}`);
        }
      } else {
        errorCells.push(`R${rowIndex + 4}`);
      }
    }

    const validationresult = await validateIds({ validateUsers: userIdArray });

    p.forEach(async (row, rowIndex) => {
      let newErrors = [];
      const {
        [headers.indexOf("First Name")]: firstName,
        [headers.indexOf("Last Name")]: lastName,
        [headers.indexOf("Email")]: email,
        [headers.indexOf("Phone Number")]: phoneNumber,
        [headers.indexOf("Branch")]: branch,
        [headers.indexOf("Department")]: department,
        [headers.indexOf("Staff Id")]: staffId,
        [headers.indexOf("Is Hod")]: isHod,
        [headers.indexOf("Working Status")]: workingStatus,
        [headers.indexOf("Employment Type")]: employmentType,
        [headers.indexOf("Staff Type")]: staffType,
        [headers.indexOf("Teaching Type")]: teachingType,
        [headers.indexOf("Experience Verification")]: experienceVerification,
        [headers.indexOf("Designation")]: designation,
        [headers.indexOf("DOB")]: dob,
        [headers.indexOf("Joining Date")]: joiningDate,
        [headers.indexOf("Leaving Date")]: leavingDate,
      } = row;
      if (!firstName) {
        newErrors.push(0);
      }
      if (!lastName) {
        newErrors.push(1);
      }
      if (!phoneNumber) {
        newErrors.push(3);
      }
      //Add validation for staff ID
      //Add for branch
      //Change for derpartment
      if (!department) {
        newErrors.push(5);
      }
      if (!staffId || !isUnique(staffIds, staffId)) {
        newErrors.push(6);
      }
      if (!isValidPhone(phoneNumber)) {
        newErrors.push(7);
      }
      const emailRegex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
      if (!emailRegex.test(email.text)) {
        newErrors.push(2);
      }
      if (isHod !== "Yes" && isHod !== "No") {
        console.log(isHod, "pushing...");
        newErrors.push(7);
      }
      if (workingStatus !== "Not Working" && workingStatus !== "Working") {
        newErrors.push(8);
      }
      if (
        employmentType !== "Regular" &&
        employmentType !== "Temporary" &&
        employmentType !== "Visiting"
      ) {
        newErrors.push(9);
      }

      if (
        teachingType !== "Class" &&
        teachingType !== "Lab" &&
        teachingType !== "Both"
      ) {
        newErrors.push(11);
      }
      if (staffType !== "Teaching" && staffType !== "Non Teaching") {
        newErrors.push(10);
      }
      if (
        experienceVerification !== "Not Done" &&
        experienceVerification !== "Done"
      ) {
        newErrors.push(12);
      }
      if (!isValidDate(dob)) {
        newErrors.push(14);
      }
      if (!isValidDate(joiningDate)) {
        newErrors.push(15);
      }
      if (!leavingDate === "" && !isValidDate(leavingDate)) {
        newErrors.push(16);
      }
      // change designation
      if (typeof designation == "array") {
        designation.forEach((des) => {
          if (
            !((des.name == "") | undefined | null) ||
            !isValidDate(des.fromDate) ||
            !isValidDate(des.toDate)
          ) {
            newErrors.push(13);
          }
        });
      }
      if (firstName && lastName) {
        console.log("ADDING USER ID");
        const userId = `${firstName.toLowerCase()}.${lastName.toLowerCase()}@${collegeShortForm}`;
        // console.log(
        //    "hemlo", worksheet.getCell(`R${rowIndex + 4}`), !worksheet.getCell(`R${rowIndex + 4}`).value
        // );
        if (!worksheet.getCell(`R${rowIndex + 4}`).value) {
          worksheet.getCell(`R${rowIndex + 4}`).value = userId;
          console.log("ADDED:", worksheet.getCell(`R${rowIndex + 4}`).value);
          // Call your validateIdAPI function here using userId
          const isUserIdAvailable = validationresult.response.some((item) => {
            console.log(item.userId, userId);
            if (item.userId === userId) {
              return item.availability;
            }
          });
          console.log("isUserIdAvailable", isUserIdAvailable);

          if (!isUserIdAvailable) {
            console.log("ERROR NOT VALID");
            newErrors.push(17);
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log("error can't generate");
        newErrors.push(17);
      }

      if (newErrors.length > 0) {
        const newworkbook = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: "array",
          cellHTML: true,
          cellStyles: true,
          cellDates: true,
          cellText: true,
          dateNF: "DD-MM-YYYY",
        });
        const newworksheet = newworkbook.Sheets[newworkbook.SheetNames[0]];
        const invalidRowCells = getRowCellRefs(
          newworksheet,
          rowIndex + 3,
          newErrors
        );
        errorCells.push(...invalidRowCells);
      }

      console.log(newErrors, errorCells);
    });
    worksheet.getRow(1).fill = {
      type: "pattern",
      pattern: "solid",
      fgColor: { argb: "FBE0EE" },
    };
    if (errorCells.length > 0) {
      const redFill = {
        type: "pattern",
        pattern: "solid",
        fgColor: { argb: "FFFF0000" },
      };
      const whiteFill = {
        type: "pattern",
        pattern: "solid",
        fgColor: { argb: "FFFFFFFF" },
      };
      worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, (row, rowNumber) => {
        // Iterate through each cell in the row
        row.eachCell({ includeEmpty: true }, (cell, colNumber) => {
          const fill = cell.fill;
          
          // Check if the cell has a red background color
          if (fill && fill.type === 'pattern' && fill.pattern === 'solid' && fill.fgColor && fill.fgColor.argb === 'FFFF0000') {
            cell.fill = null;
          }
        });
      });
      errorCells.forEach((cell) => {
        const cellRef = worksheet.getCell(cell);
        // console.log("TO BE RED CELL", cellRef, cellRef.fill);
        cellRef.fill = redFill;
        // console.log("RED CELL", cellRef, cellRef.fill);
      });

      const updatedBuffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
      const blob = new Blob([updatedBuffer], {
        type: "application/octet-stream",
      });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.download = "updated.xlsx";
      link.click();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      setAddData(errorCells.length);
    } else {
      setAddData(p);
    }
  };

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
};

function generateUserId(firstName, lastName, collegeName, teacherIdFormat) {
  return teacherIdFormat === 0
    ? `${firstName}.${lastName}@${collegeName}`
    : `${lastName}.${firstName}@${collegeName}`;
}
```

I have implemented this color change functionality by making a simple nodejs program. there it was working but in the above code same functionality is not working
I am providing that working node code also:

```
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
const path = require('path');

const inputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'template.xlsx');
const outputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'template_modified.xlsx');
// Load the existing workbook
const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();



workbook.xlsx.readFile(inputFilePath)
  .then(() => {
    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Test Worksheet'); 

    // Check if the worksheet exists
    if (!worksheet) {
      throw new Error('Worksheet not found.');
    }

    // Iterate through each row in the worksheet
    worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: true }, (row, rowNumber) => {a
      // Iterate through each cell in the row
      row.eachCell({ includeEmpty: true }, (cell, colNumber) => {
        const fill = cell.fill;
        
        // Check if the cell has a red background color
        if (fill && fill.type === 'pattern' && fill.pattern === 'solid' && fill.fgColor && fill.fgColor.argb === 'FFFF0000') {
          // Change the background color to none
          cell.fill = null
        }
      });
    });

    // Save the modified workbook
    const outputFilePath = 'template_modified.xlsx'; 
    return workbook.xlsx.writeFile(outputFilePath);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Red cells changed to no coloured.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  });
```

Please tell me why it is not working in above code